# Peak Current vs RMS Current when calculating Reactance

Tags: voltage, current, induction, rms, reactance

I am having a hard time getting a grip on AC circuit analysis. I have been taking my peak voltage/current and converting it to RMS current and RMS voltage so I can use ohms law and things like that to calculate values.
I just got introduced to Inductive Reactance and Capacitive Reactance but am confused as to how it relates to RMS and Peak values. Should I still make sure I am using RMS values with these equations or do I use peak?
For instance:
What inductance draws a 160mA RMS current when connected to a 110V, 25Hz source?
Assuming I want RMS values I first solve for the resistance of the circuit.

R=V/I, R=110V/160mA, R=687.5 OHMS, R=X

So my Inductive Reactance will be 687.5. I can sub this into the equation and solve for Inductance

X=2πfL, 687.5=2π(25Hz)L, L=4.3H

So my answer would be 4.3 Henries. However I began to second guess myself and wonder if I should be using peak current instead. That makes the current from 160mA to around 226mA.

Calculating resistance with peak values.

R=V/I, R=110V/226mA, R=486.7 OHMS

Calculate Reactance with 486.7 OHMS

X=2πfL, 486.7=2π(25Hz)L, L=3.1H

Just wondering if anyone could provide some insight into this, been looking all over for answers. Most places don't go into great detail.

Comment: RMS voltage use RMS current to get X(f) or use Vpp(f) and Ipp(f) to get same X(f) , If you assume Vrms and measure Ipp then you must convert to the same units.

Comment: for more insight https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/417666/can-t-reproduce-oscillations-using-a-simple-inductor-capacitor-circuit/417695#417695

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BMsQ.png

Comment: Be sure to differentiate between Resistance (R) and impedance (\$Z=\sqrt{R^2+X^2}\$).  Getting in the habit now will save you confusion and effort later.

Comment: @KH The formula you give is for the **magnitude** of the impedance: \$|Z| = \sqrt{R^2+X^2}\$. Impedance is a complex value. Your formula does not differentiate between capacitive reactance and inductive reactance, where in reality their impedances are different.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson  I forgot the absolute value symbol too =).  I just threw the formula in there  to differentiate R from Z.  I would normally use just \$X\$ to imply total reactance (\$X_L+X_C\$).  Is this severely improper or just nonideal?

Comment: For a series RLC circuit the total reactance is \$(X_L - X_C)\$ and I am fine with that, but **impedance** is a much more general and useful concept than reactance.

Answer (score 1):

RMS voltage use RMS current to get X(f) or use Vpp(f) and Ipp(f) to get same X(f) .

If you assume Vrms and measure Ipp then you must convert to the same units. That's all.

Sorry type on graph meant 688 not 488
[image]

[for more insight](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/417666)